# Pass an interface from class to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, interface, serializable

If i have an object form interface in my class, how i can pass it to activity?

My solution was to change it as static object, it's work fine but sometimes it create a memory leaks because of all the old references which the garbage collector cannot collect, and i cannot implement 'Serializable' on my interface.

```
public class MyClass {
     protected OnStringSetListener onstringPicked;
        public interface OnStringSetListener {
            void OnStringSet(String path);

        }
    //......//
      public void startActivity(){
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,Secound.class);
                // ?! intent.putExtra("TAG", inter);
                context.startActivity(intent);
      }
}
```

Comment: Use `Parcelable`.. It is built for Android..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, using [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) would be a nice choice. Actually bundles internally use [Parcelables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). So, this approach would be a good way to go with.

Suppose you would like to pass an object of type class `MyClass` to another Activity, all you need is adding two methods for compressing/uncompressing to/from a bundle.

To Bundle:

```
public Bundle toBundle(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // Add the class properties to the bundle
    return bundle;
}
```

From Bundle:

```
public static MyClass fromBundle(Bundle bundle){
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    // populate properties here
    return obj;
}
```

**Note:** Then you can simply pass bundles to another activities using `putExtra`. Note that handling bundles is much simpler than Parcelables.

Answer (score 0):

Passing in custom objects is a little more complicated. You could just mark the class as Serializable
and let Java take care of this. However, on the android, there is a serious performance hit that comes with using Serializable. The solution is to use Parcelable.

[Extra info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)